PhpStorm EAP not showing in GitHub Desktop External Editor list
When I install JetBrains PhpStorm Early Access Program (e.g. PhpStorm 2024.2 EAP) in my WIN11 it is not showing up in GitHub Desktop's External Editor's List.

Trick:

open Registry Editor (RUN -> regedit)

go to



HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall


Rename the folder 'PhpStorm 242.15523.20' to 'PhpStorm 2024.2'

Re-open Github Desktop



OP did not specify the OS. This answer is only for Windows.

@SimaoGomesViana to be fair, the answer IS from OP.

Sorry, my comment was not clear enough. The original post does not specify the OS. This answer is only for Windows so maybe the question could be extended to include this information.
